# Почему не срабатывает функция

Tags: javascript, html

Есть textbox c событием onclick:

```
<input type="text" value="Текст" id="text" onclick="">
```

Если в событие onclick записать напрямую:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('text').value = '';"
```

То все работает (текст удаляется), но если это записать в файл js, предварительно подключенный, в котором будет функция:

```
function clear(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = '';
}
```

И в onclick вставить:

```
onclick="clear('text')"
```

То ничего не происходит. Скажите пожалуйста, что не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clear() является методом JavaScript, по этому он не вызывает функцию. Поменяйте имя функции.

```js
function delValue() {
  document.getElementById('textBoxt').value = '';
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Текст" id="textBoxt" onclick="delValue()">
```